# disable Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 find option which occurs when clicking Ctrl+F in vb

Tags: vb.net

disable Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 find option which occurs when clicking Ctrl+F in vb

When shifting to other form from the webview form, the find option does not gets suppressed or hide.
How to handle this in vb

Comment: Does this have nothing to do with vb? It seems like a Visual Studio question

Comment: At this time, WebView2 doesn't expose any API that allows to handle the Find tool window. Because of the state of the underlying InputInjector, even trying to set focus to the Textfield UI element may cause the parent Window to get stuck. The implementation of this functionality is *under consideration*, though